# build Interface to define two final classes for typing a field

Tags: java

I have two `final` classes : `Scanner` and `CsvReader`.

I want a field : `private MyInterface scan;` able to receive a *Scanner instance* or a *CsvReader instance*, and only thoses types.

How build *MyInterface* ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both `Scanner` and `CsvReader` implement `MyInterface`.

Then you can build `MyInterface` by including all the methods that `Scanner` and `CsvReader` share - say a `read` method for example.

Now you can write:

```
MyInterface scan1 = new Scanner();
MyInterface scan2 = new CsvReader();

scan1.read();
scan2.read();
```

Comment: Weren't `Scanner` and `CsvReader` final?

Comment: @Keppil even if they are final, you can still have them implement an interface. Unless the question means that he is NOT able to change those 2 classes at all...

Comment: Yes, of course you can. I interpreted the question as though OP couldn't change them, but I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: @Keppil final has a specific meaning. If he meant something different he should clarify his question.

Comment: Well, if you want to take that approach to answering questions, that is up to you.

Comment: @Keppil I am not taking any approach - I am answering the question as it is without second guessing what the OP meant. If he means something else (which is possible) he will leave a comment and I'll delete my answer. But he might also actually mean what he says.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to provide factory methods who takes a Scanner or CsvReader and create anonymous classes delegating the behaviour to them.

```
interface MyInterface {
        void read();
    }

public class TestClass {

    class CsvReader {
        public void read() {
            System.out.println("CSV reader is reading");
        }
    }

    class Scanner {
        public void read() {
            System.out.println("Scanner is reading");
        }
    }

    public static MyInterface newInstance(final CsvReader reader) {
        return new MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void read() {
                reader.read();
            }
        };
    }

    public static MyInterface newInstance(final Scanner scanner){
        return new MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void read() {
                scanner.read();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Pattern Design solution. I was badly focused on Interface generics.